# BigQuery SQL one hot encode from a long to a wide table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a `main` table that looks like:

```
id | name | age 
1    John   20
2    David  35
3    Alice  27
```

I have a second table `special` that encodes a 1:M relationship:

```
id | specialid 
1    1577
1    2868
2    9375
3    1309
3    5240
3    2346
```

How can I join and one hot encode `special` to `main` to produce a table as below:

```
id | name | age | 1577 | 2868 | 9375 | 1309 | 5240 | 2346
1    John   20     1       1      0      0     0      0
2    David  35     0       0      1      0     0      0
3    Alice  27     0       0      0      1     1      1
```

If an additional person existed that shared an identical code, this obviously should use the same column:

```
id | name | age | 1577 | 2868 | 9375 | 1309 | 5240 | 2346 | 2223
1    John   20     1       1      0      0     0      0       0
2    David  35     0       0      1      0     0      0       0
3    Alice  27     0       0      0      1     1      1       0    
4    Sarah  32     0       1      0      1     1      0       1
```

This is for the purposes of building a machine learning model. In my actual use case, there are 7624 unique special codes. Is there anyway to automate the process of building a column for each unique special code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my actual use case, there are 7624 unique special codes. Is there anyway to automate the process of building a column for each unique special code?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp table data as
select *
from `project.dataset.main`
left join `project.dataset.special`
using(id);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
  SELECT id, name, age, """ || 
    STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(specialid = '""" || specialid || """', 1, 0)) AS _""" || REPLACE(specialid, '.', '_'), ', ') 
  || """
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY id, name, age
  """
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT specialid 
    FROM data
    ORDER BY specialid
  )
);
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I am getting told the query produced by STRING_AGG is invalid. Would your query change if I told you `specialid` was actually a string and not an integer?

Comment: sure, see update in answer to support specialid as string as opposed as int64 as I thought initially

Comment: This is great, thank you! This has nearly solved my problem and also taught me about dynamic SQL, which I had not used before. I am encountering a problem because some of my `specialid` columns have a `.`, as in `7564.2`. This is causing a `Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "." `. How can I dynamically deal with the `.`?

Comment: what you want the column name to be in such a case? I would suggest just replace `.` with `_` if this works for you i can update the answer - unless you will be able to do it by yourself. let me know

Comment: Yes, that would be reasonable.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how to break this into smaller pieces? I keep running into an `exceeds CPU time limits` error.

Comment: sure. I think I do. will look into this tomorrow - so you have about 7600 unique codes - right? how many rows your tables - main and special? is there anything else special about your use case that potentially can help? Also, question - is this one time task that you need to accomplish or it is something that you plan to run frequently?

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is a one time task. My "main" table has 7,658,916 rows and is 5.11 GB in total size. The "special table" has 12,967,523 rows and is  
898.03 MB in size. What may help is to know each row has a year value (2005-2020), so it may help to divide it up by years.

Comment: Any luck? I still have not figured anything out.

Comment: sorry, got stuck with some duties. still planning to get back to your case :o(

Comment: No worries, I appreciate it! Take your time, this is obviously just charity! :)

Comment: to troubleshoot I will need your help (or if you can somehow share your data or similar fake data with me) . so first please try to limit number of code involved in pivoting  - to do so just add limit 100 to the very last subquery `SELECT DISTINCT specialid 
    FROM data
    ORDER BY specialid` so it will become `SELECT DISTINCT specialid 
    FROM data
    ORDER BY specialid LIMIT 100` - then change 100 to 1000 and so on  - we need to find at which point we are getting the problem - this will help us in identifying next steps/direction. please do this "excercise" and let me know result

Comment: one more question meantime  - how long script was running before getting `exceeds CPU time limits` error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223531/discussion-between-dylan-russell-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: The limit seems to be between 3000 and 3500.

Comment: so you can try to process your data separately in batches of 2000-3000 specialid's - as you have about 7700 of such - you will end up with three or four tables - then you just join them by id.

Comment: Thats what I thought - How can I specify which `specialid`s though? `Limit 3000` will always do the first 3000 - how do I make it run in batches?

Comment: simplest approach would be using OFFSET clause. see [LIMIT and OFFSET clauses](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_and_offset_clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `countif()` and aggregation:

```
select id, name, age,
       countif(s.specialid = 1577) as num_1577,
       countif(s.specialid = 2868) as num_2868,
       countif(s.specialid = 9375) as num_9375,
       countif(s.specialid = 1309) as num_1309,
       countif(s.specialid = 5240) as num_5240,
       countif(s.specialid = 2346) as num_2346,
       countif(s.specialid = 2223) as num_2223
from main m left join
     special s
     on m.id = s.id
group by id, name, age;
```

Comment: In my actual use case, there are 7624 special codes. Is there anyway to automate the process of building a column for each unique special code? I will update my question.

Comment: @DylanRussell . . . I think you would need to use dynamic SQL. BigQuery does allow up to 10,000 columns per table so at least you *can* do what you want.