# How to pivot records to multi-hot encoding in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a `records` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `records` 
(
    `ID1` INT64,
    `ID2` DATE,
    `EVENT` INT64,
);
```

This table has some records like:

```
INSERT `records` (ID1, ID2, EVENT)
VALUES (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-01-10'), 111),
       (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-01-10'), 111),
       (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-01-10'), 222),
       (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-03-15'), 333),
       (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-03-15'), 111),
       (1, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-07-22'), 444),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-02-17'), 999),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-02-17'), 888),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-02-17'), 888),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-02-17'), 555),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-02-17'), 666),
       (2, PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2022-07-22'), 111)
```

And I have a separate dictionary (or vocabulary) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_vocabs` 
(
    `EVENT` INT64,
    `DESCRIPTION` STRING,
);
```

Table `t_vocabs` contains all unique values for `EVENT`:

```
INSERT `t_vocabs` (EVENT, DESCRIPTION)
VALUES (111, 'desc1'),
       (222, 'desc2'),
       (333, 'desc3'),
       (444, 'desc4'),
       (555, 'desc5'),
       (666, 'desc6'),
       (777, 'desc7'),
       (888, 'desc8'),
       (999, 'desc9'),
       (123, 'desc10'),
       (456, 'desc111')
```

Therefore, `records` would look like this:

[image]

And the vocabulary table would look like this:

[image]

I need to convert `records` to multi-hot encoding in which for each `ID1` and `ID2` I have one record, with the number of columns equal to the unique number of events in `t_vocabs` and the values equal to 1 when that relevant event exists in `records` and 0 otherwise.

For this example, it'd be like:

[image]

Note, I have tried

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    `records`
PIVOT
    (COUNT(*) FOR EVENT IN (111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 123, 456))
```

And this does the job, but the issue is that the `t_vocabs` is a big table and I can't list all `EVENT` values manually in this query. When I try to select events from another table (e.g. following query) it doesn't like the select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `records`
PIVOT(COUNT(*) FOR EVENT IN (SELECT EVENT FROM `t_vocabs`))
```

Comment: and searching for pivot didn't give you and hint?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just updated the question about using pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from records 
pivot (count(*) for event in (''' || string_agg('' || event, ',' order by event) || "))"
from t_vocabs
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, works perfectly for the example! Do you think there is anyway to set a destination for the resulted table? It doesn't let me do that because ```configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts```. My actual data is large and I'm not able to run this without setting a destination table.

Comment: This is the error when I run on my data where ```records``` table has 3B records and ```t_vocabs``` has a few hundred values: ```Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.. at [2:1]```

Comment: what the number of the rows in vocabulary table?

Comment: 600 rows including 600 distinct event.

Comment: for troubleshooting purposes - try to lower number of rows in this table - let's say down to 10, so to see if problem with number of events or with number of rows in records table

Comment: So when I reduce vocabulary to 10 it works fine and fast. The problem seems to be the large vocabulary. I also tried to remove the immediate execution and manually insert the 600 vocabulary values in pivot and define a destination table, but I got the same error : ```Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex```

Comment: As a quick fix, I can probably just break the vocabulary to multiple tables and do the pivot separately and concat the final results.

Comment: sure. this is an option. yet another option is to revisit your requirements (in case if you allowed) - usually having that wide table is not too practical

Comment: Thank you though, this was a great help!

Comment: I am a novice at SQL 
@MikhailBerlyant could you please explain your query bit by bit. I also found your similar answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419741/bigquery-sql-one-hot-encode-from-a-long-to-a-wide-table).
I am trying to do this in SnowflakeSQL and it is giving me errors